# how to use Express 4 with Socket.io 0.9.x?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am a ios developer, the Objc-Socket.io library is still support socket.io 0.9.x

I use Express 4.0 with my nodejs server:

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express')();
var io = require('socket.io');

io.listen(express);
```

But I run it in terminal, it throw me an error:

```
% node test

Socket.IO's `listen()` method expects an `http.Server` instance
as its first parameter. Are you migrating from Express 2.x to 3.x?
If so, check out the "Socket.IO compatibility" section at:
https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should do the trick:

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app).listen(1337);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    //emit and listen messages
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    //do something
});
```